# Is it possible to target the iPhone with compatible LLVM IR/bitcode from a non-Apple operating system?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gcc, llvm, clang

OK, putting aside the obvious packaging and signing issues, would it be possible to compile IOS/iPhone compatible executables, by using correctly constructed LLVM bitcode (IR) from a non-Apple operating system, such as Linux or Windows, i.e. by utilising some combination of Open Source compiler infrastructure such as LLVM, Clang or GCC?

Basically, what I'm contemplating is

1. Compile a pre-existing cross-platform SDK (IOS-compatible) to LLVM Intermediate Representation (IR/bitcode).
2. Analyse and identify the IOS-specific LLVM (IR) function calls within this layer, using LLVM analysis tools.
3. After the compilation of the SDK to LLVM IR on the non-Apple system, *replace* the Apple/IOS-generated-LLVM-bitcode-SDK-representation within the corresponding LLVM IR function calls generated by the non-Mac host.
4. [possibly] employ the build flags emitted by the Mac's XCode/Clang/LLVM infrastructure, in order to build the IOS-compatible executable on the non-Apple host compilation machine (e.g. Linux or Windows).

If this is at all feasible, I would later investigate the creation of an iPhone/IOS bundle (the construction of IPA is documented, ask Google) and use the open-source Apple code-signing routines, already in use within other cross-platform IOS SDK's

Comment: Please update this question when you make progress on this! Very interesting.

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug - It's more likely an '**If** I make progress', however, it's something that's highly of interest to me. I'm not sure if I have the 'raw' computer-scientist level of understanding to pull this off :-( . I'll let you know if I [ever] find anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Java-to-IOS is being taken care of by the [RoboVM](http://www.robovm.org) project:

> Java to Native
>
> The RoboVM compiler translates Java bytecode into native ARM or x86
>   code. Apps run directly on the CPU. No interpreter or virtual machine
>   involved.

It makes use of LLVM, as my question suggested.

Also of note is the [Avian JVM](http://oss.readytalk.com/avian) project. It to can be used to compile to native and IOS binaries (by bundling the JVM), however, I'm uncertain as to the status or completeness of its user interface (UI) layer(s).

Both project appear to be in current and constant development.

Answer (score 4):

RoboVM doesn't support cross-compiling iOS apps from OSes other than Mac OS yet but we plan on supporting that in the future. Here's an iOS cross-compilation toolchain which runs on Linux that may be of interest to you: https://code.google.com/p/ios-toolchain-based-on-clang-for-linux/.